# Save the users input or response to local storage with HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have tried all the methods i can try to make data save into the web page using local storage from inputs user which they will input in the HTML Table in the input box. im tries to place a save button so as the user finished entering the data they can click and all the input will be saved and when the user wants to access the page again they will be able to retrieve all data they enter before.

I also have a date section but i would to make a day go back, so if it shows 2021 April 22  i want to show 2021 April 21 and i want to show which day is it like Monday or Tuesday under the date

Here is what i have tried so far:

```js
//For Local Storage
//var input = document.getElementById('daysFree').value;
//localStorage.setItem('daysFree', input);
//document.getElementById('daysFree').value = localStorage.getItem('daysFree'); //For getting the text back -->

//var input = document.getElementById('FY').value;
//localStorage.setItem('FY', input);
//document.getElementById('FY').value = localStorage.getItem('FY');

//var input = document.getElementById('OIR').value;
//localStorage.setItem('OIR', input);
//document.getElementById('OIR').value = localStorage.getItem('OIR');

//var input = document.getElementById('RI').value;
//localStorage.setItem('RI', input);
//document.getElementById('RI').value = localStorage.getItem('RI');

//var input = document.getElementById('PIT').value;
//localStorage.setItem('PIT', input);
//document.getElementById('PIT').value = localStorage.getItem('PIT');

//var input = document.getElementById('TI').value;
//localStorage.setItem('TI', input);
//document.getElementById('TI').value = localStorage.getItem('TI');

//For Displaying the Date 
$(document).ready(function() {
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  let qntYears = 4;
  let selectYear = $("#year");
  let selectMonth = $("#month");
  let selectDay = $("#day");
  let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

  for (var y = 0; y < qntYears; y++) {
    let date = new Date(currentYear);
    let yearElem = document.createElement("option");
    yearElem.value = currentYear
    yearElem.textContent = currentYear;
    selectYear.append(yearElem);
    currentYear--;
  }

  for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++) {
    let month = monthNames[m];
    let monthElem = document.createElement("option");
    monthElem.value = m;
    monthElem.textContent = month;
    selectMonth.append(monthElem);
  }

  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var day = d.getDate();

  selectYear.val(year);
  selectYear.on("change", AdjustDays);
  selectMonth.val(month);
  selectMonth.on("change", AdjustDays);

  AdjustDays();
  selectDay.val(day)

  function AdjustDays() {
    var year = selectYear.val();
    var month = parseInt(selectMonth.val()) + 1;
    selectDay.empty();

    //get the last day, so the number of days in that month
    var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

    //lets create the days of that month
    for (var d = 1; d <= days; d++) {
      var dayElem = document.createElement("option");
      dayElem.value = d;
      dayElem.textContent = d;
      selectDay.append(dayElem);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

</style><style>.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}

</style><style>.image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}

</style><style>.corner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}

</style><!--Header Style to Header by Logo --><style>* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-right: 770px;
  margin-top: -748px;
}

</style><style>th,
td {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5px
}

</style><style>.html2canvas {
  width: 1700px !important;
  height: 1700px !important;
}

</style><style>table tr {
  background: #ffdead;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: white;
}

text-align: center;
</style><style>body {
  background-color: #66b032;
}

h1,
th,
td {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.0.2/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../extensions/Editor/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.0.2/css/dataTables.dateTime.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../extensions/Editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css">
  <title>AP Safety</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="section">
    <form name="apSafety" id="" apSafety "" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateChecklistForm()">
      <div class="aligned">
        <span>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<img src="Walgreens.png" width="120" height="130" alt=""></span> &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        <b><h1>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Woodland DC </h1></b><b><h1 style="font-size:70px;">&nbsp;Safety Stats</h1></b>
      </div>
      <table class="center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>April Daily<br>Stats<br>&emsp;<br></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>FY Goal % &emsp;<br></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>OIR &emsp;<br></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>Recordable Incidents &emsp;<br></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>PIT Incidents &emsp;<br></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>Total Incidents &emsp;<br></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>Days OIR Free &emsp;<br></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            &emsp;
            <select style="height:60px;width:95px;font-size:25px;font-weight: bold;" id="year"></select>
            <select style="height:60px;width:95px;font-size:25px;font-weight: bold;" id="month"></select>
            <!-- Today's Date is : &nbsp;<label id="text"></label>-->
            <select style="height:60px;width:95px;font-size:25px;font-weight: bold;" id="day"></select>
            &emsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &emsp;
            <label for="FY"></label><br><input style="background-color: #151313;text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="FY" name="FY" value=" "><br> &emsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &emsp;
            <label for="OIR"></label><br><input style="background-color: #339214;text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;color: ##151313;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="OIR" name="OIR" value=" "><br> &emsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &emsp;
            <label for="RI"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="RI" name="RI" value=" "><br> &emsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &emsp;
            <label for="PIT"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="PIT" name="PIT" value=" "><br> &emsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &emsp;
            <label for="TI"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="TI" name="TI" value=" "><br> &emsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &emsp;
            <label for="daysFree"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="daysFree" name="daysFree" value=" "><br> &emsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <b><h1 style="font-size:50px;">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Push instead of Pull</h1></b>
      <div class="image">
        <span>
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<img src="Safety3.png" width="450" height="500" alt="">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<img src="Safety2.png" width="850" height="450" alt=""></span>
      </div>
      <div class="corner">
        <span>
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;<img src="Safety1.png" width="255" height="75" alt=""></span>
      </div>
      <button onclick="save_data()" type="button">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any methods that you claim you've tried...are you sure you've tried them all? If something you've tried didn't work, tell us what it is and what/how exactly it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I would've commented this.

Using JS to save a users input is very hard. PHP is very hard, but simpler.

Firstly, a new MySQL database should be created. To do this you must know how to code MySQL.

Create a new local server with saba on a linux machine. (learn how to here> https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-file-server).

Connect the MySQL database to the server.

Allow PHP on the server.

Connect the PHP to the server.

In the samba file (www/html) on your linux machine create a new file called 'php.ini' and add `file_uploads = on`. This will allow PHP and user uploads.

````
Make a new php file called ```connect-server.php``. In this put in ```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

```
````

This will connect PHP to local server, allowing uploads.

I can't give you every single line of code, but if you need help go here >

https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp